# I have a c# code to turn on/off keyboard led. I want to know working of code

Tags: c#

This is the code i want to be familiar with:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags,
    UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    const int CAPSLOCK = 0x14;
    const int NUMLOCK = 0x90;
    const int SCROLLLOCK = 0x91; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keybd_event(CAPSLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
        keybd_event(CAPSLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has nothing to understand. It just calls [keybd_event](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event) to simulate the capslock key event...

Comment: It´s quite unclear what you mean. Where exactly is your problem understanding the code? Don´t you know what a `const` is? Don´t you know `extern`? ...

Comment: I dont know how this function is working . I mean the values 0x1, 0x2 etc. what is purpose of UIntPtr and how | gate is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From msdn website:

> keybd_event function Synthesizes a keystroke. The system can use such
>   a synthesized keystroke to generate a WM_KEYUP or WM_KEYDOWN message.
>   The keyboard driver's interrupt handler calls the keybd_event
>   function.

1. bVk - A virtual-key code. The code must be a value in the range 1 to
   254.
2. bScan - A hardware scan code for the key.
3. dwFlags - Controls various aspects of function operation.

Everything you need to know about this function is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

You can probably see that your `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` and `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` are flags. By using `flag1 | flag2 | flag3` you can pass multiple flags.

Also probably the most important part is this:

> Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.